# select and group from based on another table result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables; hotelservices and guestorder

hotelservices

```
s_id(pk)    serviceType    serviceName
```

guestOrder table:

```
g_id(pk)    serviceType    totalAmount    balanceDue    PaidAmount    orderDate
```

I want to get the sum of totalAmount,balanceDue,PaidAmount based upon the serviceType from the hotelservice table.

That is, it will iterate and group the hotelservices.serviceType and get the associated data from the guestorder table based upon the serviceType column.

My attempt so far:

```
SELECT
 g.OrderDate as saleDate,
 g.ServiceType,
 sum(g.TotalAmount) as TotalSales,
 sum(g.BalanceDue) as TotalBalanceDue,
 sum(g.PaidAmount) as TotalPaid,
 h.ServicesType as services
 FROM guestorder as g join hotelservices as h on g.ServiceType=h.ServicesType
 group by saleDate
```

but it is not what i want. i need it to show others serviceType even if it has nothing in the guestorder.i don't know if i am making sense at all. thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIU you should use `LEFT JOIN` clause.

Comment: where is the foreign key in your guestOrder table to join the tables?

Comment: @JohnRuddell It's not servicetype? (although there must be a typo somewhere there)

Comment: @Strawberry im guessing thats what it is.. but the OP didn't specify in the schema posted especially since there was the (pk) specified. so I wanted to ask for clarification

Comment: Good effort but, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @John Ruddell no fk on guestorder table for the serviceType, my mistake

Comment: @user1496307 its ok, I just wanted clarification... if all you have to go on for joining the tables is the serviceType then see my answer.. you should try and use coalesce() to handle the null values :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reverse your join, turn it into a LEFT OUTER JOIN and fix the problem with your GROUP BY, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    g.OrderDate as saleDate,
    g.ServiceType,
    sum(g.TotalAmount) as TotalSales,
    sum(g.BalanceDue) as TotalBalanceDue,
    sum(g.PaidAmount) as TotalPaid,
    h.ServicesType as services
FROM 
    hotelservices as h 
    LEFT JOIN guestorder as g ON g.ServiceType=h.ServicesType
GROUP BY
    g.OrderDate,
    g.ServiceType,
    h.ServicesType;
```

Comment: i think i can use your response and edit it to suit my solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`i need it to show others serviceType even if it has nothing in the guestorder`

from this im assuming you have data that doesn't match... 
when you use a JOIN or INNER JOIN (because thats what JOIN defaults to) you are filtering out anything that doesn't match. if you want to join without filtering then do a LEFT JOIN..

you should add COALESCE() so that you don't have NULL values like so

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(g.OrderDate, '') saleDate,
    COALESCE(g.ServiceType, '') guestServiceType,
    COALESCE(sum(g.TotalAmount), 0) TotalSales,
    COALESCE(sum(g.BalanceDue), 0) TotalBalanceDue,
    COALESCE(sum(g.PaidAmount), 0) TotalPaid,
    h.ServicesType as services
FROM hotelservices h 
LEFT JOIN guestorder g ON g.ServiceType = h.ServicesType
GROUP BY h.serviceType, saleDate
```

## NOTE:

your select needs to be FROM the hotel services table so that way you have all of the service types.. then LEFT JOIN the guestorder table so that way there is no filtering.

Comment: your suggestion is usable and i will experiment with it to see how it will work for me. thanks

Comment: @user1496307 my pleasure :) you can always change the default value you put in the COALESCE().. so I just put in a 0 for when you sum and an empty string '' for when its a string value... :) if you could mark one of the answers as accepted it would be appreciated and it keeps the community clean and whole :) thanks!!